# Eclipse has stopped opening the .java, and now it always opens the .class

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, debugging

I am working in Eclipse on a java Spring environment, it is not a new project, I have been working on it for some time, it is composed of several projects, some WEB projects that call other LIB projects. All these projects are linked by means of dependencies in their respective Pom.xml. Until now, when debugging the application, when putting breakpoints, the .java classes of the corresponding project were opened, but now I am not able to, I don't know why now what opens me are the .class, I don't know why now it behaves like this. Any idea?

Do I need to provide more information? I have been working for months now, and it has never happened to me before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following, I have a complex project, which includes several LIB and WEB projects, linked between them by pom.xml
Until now I had only had to use dependencies of the LIBs in the WEB projects.
Now I had a projectA_LIB, a projectB_LIB and a projectB_WEB, I only need the dependency of the projectA_LIB in the projectB_LIB, that is from where I am going to consume it, but that makes that a conflict is created, and for that reason only the RELEASE was opened in the server, and therefore only opened the .class.

**The SOLUTION**: to declare the dependency of projectA_LIB in projectB_WEB, this way both projects share the same SNAPSHOT and this failure stops occurring, so that degug can be done in the normal way.